# How to make a payment system that pays the users for doing some stuff?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

I am working on a react website where the users can write and get paid for it. Everywhere tutorials are about how do we (as a developer) receive money but I want to know how can I transfer money to the user who wrote for example wrote an article and if some conditions are met then the user will be paid some $$. Is there a way to do this task via Paypal? It would be a great help

Thanks!

Comment: Like there are many platforms such as youtube, skillshare, udemy where creators get paid for making videos. How do creators get the payment?

Comment: "How can I pay people?" isn't a programming problem. Find a service that does what you want to do, read their documentation, then come here if you still have a specific programming problem.

Comment: You can research about the payment system of platforms like youtube, udemy, skillshare.

Answer (score 0):

For PayPal you can [request access to Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/#link-getaccesstopaypalpayouts).

The important thing is to first be granted live access for your business use case; then there are API-based and web-based (spreadsheet upload) ways of using it, which you can review in the Payouts documentation.